# Error 115 Type 'Excel.IExcelDataReader' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, excel, exceldatareader

I have a vb.net application with excel export and import. I am not much familiar with this application as my ec-colleague left this to me without much information. Now when i am trying to build the application its showing the following error

```
Error   115 Type 'Excel.IExcelDataReader' is not defined.   E:\CManager\CManager\\Win764\CManager\MyApp.vb  2376    28  ContributionManager
```

I tried to get its dll but couldnt find any.

Can anybody please help on this...

Comment: its may be some third party tools for excel files.check if some dll is missing.

Comment: @akhilkumar yes it is. But whenever i am trying to add dlls its saying its already existing in the solution

Comment: please remove all the existing dlls realted to exceldatareader and add once more.it may be because of different versions.

Comment: Yes..it is resolved!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the existing dlls and added once again! its resolved

Answer (score 1):

so.. first 
[Add Referente to your Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx) to  Microsoft.Office.Interop, in COM section

in your Form

```
 Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
 Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

and use

```
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

 xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
 xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
```

'write sometring on sheet 
'and savt it !

```
   xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\Reports\" & worker & Id & ".xlsx")

    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
```

Answer (score 0):

[ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)

...btw. Have you ever heard of that google thingy ;)